# Fix error in UEFI Firmware on Huawei MateBook X Pro

Tags: boot, usb, linux-mint

After trying to install Linux Mint on a USB flash drive (the same one upon which the Live USB had been set up), I have two entries listed in the UEFI setup program for the same hard drive (even after unplugging the flash drive) as shown in [this screenshot](http://photos.app.goo.gl/g4KmQnSKp5GuyYrEA).

Attempting to boot from the first one lands me in a grub command shell (obviously it's looking for the USB and can't find it), while the second one boots Windows normally.

I think this was caused by the fact that I disabled the hard drive from the setup program before installing Mint, as I wanted to ensure that the only hard drive visible would be the USB stick (after booting to RAM and repartitioning the stick). But this landed me in "OEM Configuration Mode" where the hard drive was still visible.

My immediate first thought was to reboot from the USB normally, but stupid me was too lazy to do so and as such, I have now wasted hours when that simple first step would have taken ~10 seconds! Instead I thought I could just use the OEM mode to install Mint and everything would be hunky dory...which it kinda is; I mean both OSs boot fine (when the USB is plugged in) but I am the kind of person who is annoyed by things not being **exactly** how he wants them, or how they should be.

It also requires spamming F12 on boot in order to boot Windows, since the default option seems stuck on booting Mint. This is not ideal since I'll still be using Windows 99% of the time.

As such, I'm looking for a way to remove the erroneous drive entry. A non-destructive method would be best, but if I had to completely reflash the UEFI firmware that would also be acceptable (as long as it doesn't touch the hard drive). MTIA! :-)

**Update:** The photo link provided above shows two bootable drives, both named the same, but one of them is my USB stick...I think. It doesn't show up as "SanDisk Cruzer Switch" anymore whereas I previously had that **and** the two Samsung drive entries (but only 1 actual Samsung drive). Booting Mint still works so I guess my UEFI firmware now thinks that the Cruzer Switch is a Samsung SSD! Weird!

Comment: You write " have two entries listed in the UEFI setup program for the same hard drive (even after unplugging the flash drive)." <-- please provide a screenshot eg use your phone to take a picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same problem with Elementary OS 5: UEFI shows two bootable drives the upper one numbered 1 is the SanDisk Extreme the lower is MateBook Pro proper SSD numbered 2.

After many unsuccessful tests I stood on number 2 and noticed F5/F6 Change values. I press <kbd>F5</kbd> and number 2 swapped positions with number 1 and now MateBook Pro starts normally with Windows 10 but when I want boot Linux I press <kbd>F12</kbd> go to the lower disk (USB connected) and Elementary OS starts.

Also [this is very interesting tutorial](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=42&t=287353), which I found after Mint 19.3 installator corrupt EFI bootloader of my Huawei MateBook X Pro and system was unable to start.

Fortunately, I always have a copy of the system partition so it wasn’t big problem but the waste of time. Anyway it’s a shame that “This is crucial because there’s a bug in the Ubuntu installer, also used by Mint, which in UEFI will bollix the internal hard drive’s bootloader even if one specifies the new bootloader should be installed only to the USB drive.” and installator shouldn’t warn about it. It is interesting that the installation of Elementary OS 5.1 went smoothly.

Comment: Cheers that sounds like a good workaround!